# Web Service Passing parameter into another class/project

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, struts, apache-axis

I have created a web service (http://localhost:8081/HRIS_WS_SRV/services/HelloWS?wsdl)

```
public String hello(String name){
    return "Hello " + name;
}
```

I use bottom up for the creation (axis2 in eclipse), and in the web service assume that i have this 1 method called hello for returning a string.

What I want to ask is, the reason I want to use web service is because I have 3 application (different project in eclipse) that need to be linked and can pass parameter to the web service and then another project can get the return value.

I have created the ws server and ws client, but in the client it can only use the method and get the returned parameter directly from itself, what I want to do is for another web application to be able to access the returned value.

For Example, web application 1 send String to the web service, and then web application 2 can get the return value from the function in the web service.

Is this possible? In the future i want to use this for session passing between application, so my application 2 and 3 still can recognize the session from the application 1.

I am still new to web service, and my deadline is near (final project training program on-going). Please help guys :)
Thank you. Best Regards, Nico.

Comment: Java can return the result string only to the caller(the one who invoke the method). Why don't you just provide web service functionality from your application 1 directly? So that whenever application 2 and application 3 access the web service of application 1, u can provide the session information directly.

Comment: @additionster oh yeah? can you please explain it to me more? i have never use the web service and confused with it. I can create the web service from application 1, but what's inside it? in application 2 and 3 it will just be the client right? how can it pass the session information? thankyou..

Comment: What framework r u using on application 1?

Comment: @additionster struts + ibatis, but can i use the client with just java code? so to retrieve the session information i can just trigger the java client class.. it's so confusing i've been searching for a few days

Comment: For me, I use servlet to imitate the web service. In application 1, define a new servlet to provide ur session information. Define the url in the web.xml. When the application2 and application3 tries to access the url of application 1 servlet, supplies JSON string which contains session information. But u might need eccryption or some kind of security validation to prevent data leak.

Comment: can you give me the complete explanation in the answer page? or can you give me a mockup of your used method? Can I still use the web service for this kind of purpose?

Answer (score 2):

In web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <display-name>WebServiceServlet</display-name>
    <servlet-name>WebServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>full path of ur serlvet class</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>WebServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/UrWebServiceUrl</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

In servlet file

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
{
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("session", "sessionValue");
    PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
    pw.write(json);
    pw.close();
}
```

You might want encryption or security validation before sending out the response. From your application2 and application3 invoke the webservice.